# SQL Server 2000 - Delete file in remote

Tags: java, sql-server-2000, junit4

I am using the sp_trace_create to just test this functionality in Junit.
This is executing successfully. To be able to run this multiple times, I need to delete the trace file which is created.

```
cursor.parseCall("DECLARE @traceid int;" +
                    "EXECUTE @traceid=sp_trace_create ?,?,?,?,? ;" +
                    "SELECT @traceid");
            cursor.registerOutParameter(1, DBType.SQLT_INT);
            cursor.setIntParam(2, 2);
            cursor.setStringParam(3, "C://trace23");
            cursor.setLongParam(4, 4);
            cursor.setDateParam(5, stopDate);

            cursor.executeCall();
```

I want to know how to delete the file which is created ( in remote) in the location C://trace23.trc.

Another option is to sort of timestamp the file name with the date

```
    cursor.setStringParam(3, "C://trace"+cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

But I am not sure how correct this is.

Comment: `xp_cmdshell 'del c:\trace23.trc'` ?

Comment: Hi Adam, I gave this in the query analyser but then I got the error 'Could not find the stored procedure xp_cmdshell'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016669/getting-execute-permission-to-xp-cmdshell