# xp_cmdshell Proxy not Executing

Tags: sql-server, xp-cmdshell

I created a Proxy account with Sysadmin access.
Users use this to execute a bcp command of their choosing.

However when the users want's to execute the proc they get: **EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_cmdshell', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'**

Here is my Proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spCMDProxy 

( 
@SQLSTATEMENT VARCHAR(1000), 
@FILENAME VARCHAR(1000) 

) 
WITH ENCRYPTION 
AS 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @PrepStatement VARCHAR(1000) 
SET @PrepStatement = 'bcp ' + '"'+ @SQLSTATEMENT + '" queryout C:\SamsungEDI\' + @FILENAME + ' -U************ -P************ -c -t"||" -S UECZAERP01' 
EXEC xp_cmdshell @PrepStatement 
END
```

My Proxy account is a local Sysadmin account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, Could not execute due to the fact that the user cannot execute on xp_cmdshell:

```
USE master
GRANT EXECUTE on xp_cmdshell to [mydomain\myAccount]
```

Also found this [Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016669/getting-execute-permission-to-xp-cmdshell/2028996#2028996)