# Administrator cannot run a SQL Server query to add a Windows user with "net user /add" using xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, user-management, xp-cmdshell

I login to SQL Server with Administrator account and can execute the following query and get the result:

```
xp_cmdshell 'net user' // Works well, and displays all local Windows user accounts
```

But when I want to `'/ADD'` a new Windows user locally, with below query, the problem arise:

```
xp_cmdshell 'net user myUserName myPassWord /ADD'
```

Error message:

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_cmdshell', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.

Comment: I think your problem is pretty much this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016669/getting-execute-permission-to-xp-cmdshell

Comment: Administrator on SQL Server is not the same with Domain Administrator.